# Continuity of Cantor's function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Prove that $\psi : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow [0,1]$ 
$$ \psi \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{3^n} \right) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_n}{2^n}$$ where $\mathcal{C}$ is Cantor's set is continuity.

I don't have any idea how to prove it. How begin?

Answer (score 5):

The smallest $x$ such that $a_1=2$ is $2/3$. The largest $x$ such that $a_1=0$ is $1/3$. Therefore two numbers with different $a_1$s are at least $1/3$ apart. Likewise, two numbers with different $a_n$s are at least $1/3^n$ apart.

Conversely, if $|x-y|\lt1/3^{n}$ then $a_k(x)=a_k(y)$ for every $k\leqslant n$ hence $|\psi(x)-\psi(y)|$ is at most $(1/2)\sum\limits_{k\gt n}1/2^k=1/2^{n+1}$.

This shows that the epsilon-delta property holds, as follows: fix $\varepsilon$, pick some $n$ such that $1/2^{n+1}\lt\varepsilon$, define $\delta=1/3^{n}$, then $|x-y|\lt\delta$ implies $|\psi(x)-\psi(y)|\lt\varepsilon$. For example, $\delta=\varepsilon^2$ (is not optimal but) works when $\varepsilon\lt1$  (and the optimal value is $\delta=\varepsilon^{\log3/\log2}\approx\varepsilon^{1.585}$).